# Read Text File Using Certain Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, io

Hi Folks i was googling one more hours.i did not find anything relevant, I have  text File like this

```
 S.No Code   L Description                             Interaction Text
    1 xxxx   x xxxxxxxxxxxxx                           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    2 xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 xxxxxxxxxxxx
    3 xxxx   x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    4 xxxxx  x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    5 xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx      xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx
    6 xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
```

i was Successfully reading all contents using this code,

```
 string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

but i was stuck when split to columns.any help would appreciated

**IN short**

***how do i split every columns using fixed length of the string?***

Comment: if the spacing is tabs the split on `\t` but i have no idea what you have tried,

Comment: What do you mean by split to columns? What do you want to do after reading all the lines? Are you iterating `lines` array to split it into columns?

Comment: i have text file contains data column  like serial no,id ,code, description ,interaction text

Comment: the fields are un even datas but not excedding maximum length   ```ex id has maximum length 6```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to cut your example to save time:

```
S.No     Code
1 xxxx   x   
2 xxxxxx x   
3 xxxx   x     
4 xxxxx  x    
5 xxxxxx x     
6 xxxxxx x
```

First define the max lengths of each column, in my example:

```
 List<int> maxLengths = new List<int> { 2,7,4};

 List<List<string>> columns = new List<List<string>>(); // this is where we'll save the columns
```

Iterate over your lines and use the lengths to know which part of the substring to cut off:

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            List<string> linesColumns = new List<string>();
            int lastIndex = 0;
            foreach (int maxLength in maxLengths)
            { 
               linesColumns.Add( line.Substring(lastIndex, maxLength));
               lastIndex += maxLength;
            }
        }
```

Obviously simplified, you'll have to work on error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to split your string:

```
var columns = source.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Select(x => x.Trim());
```

And a fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjeUgR